# JDBC MySQL trying to insert multiple rows with select subquery

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Currently error 1242 happens saying that I'm getting multiple results from the query. I want all the results to be put into the equipmenthistory table though. I want to label a few items with the same bagId, and upon running the insert it does all the items at once to the same eid.

My current insert statement is below.

***into equipmenthistory (assetId, checkedOutBy, operation) values ((select assetId from equip where bagId = '1'), (select eid from employees where employeeNum = '1'),'checkedOut');***

Tables:

***equip***
assetId,
asset,
bagId

***employees***
eid,
employeeNum

***equipmenthistory***
eid,
assetId,
operation

Preferred outcome:

equipmenthistory:

eid - 1 assetId 1 operation checkedOut

eid - 1 assetId 2 operation checkedOut

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct ONE select with all your values, not a collection of selects

```
insert into equipmenthistory
            (assetId, checkedOutBy, operation)
     values 
     select assetId, employeeNum, 'checkedOut'
       from equip
       join employees using (...)
      where ....
```